# Let $v ∈ R_n$. Suppose $p_1,p_2 ∈ V$ and $n_1,n_2 ∈ V^⊥$ such that $p_1 + n_1 = v = p_2 + n_2$. Prove that $p_1 = p_2$ and $n_1 = n_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v ∈ R_n$. Suppose $p_1,p_2 ∈ V$ and $n_1,n_2 ∈ V^⊥$ such that $p_1 + n_1 = v = p_2 + n_2$. Prove that $p_1 = p_2$ and $n_1 = n_2$.

The only method that I know to prove this is by using the projection of the vectors. However, the question states that we cannot use the projection. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What is $V^\perp?$

Comment: $V^⊥$ is the orthogonal complement so the dot product of $p_1$ and $n_1$ and $p_2$ and $n_2$ would be $0$, but not sure how to apply this.

Comment: What is the relationship between $V$ and $V^\perp$?

Comment: Their sum adds up to $R_n$?

Comment: And their intersection?

Comment: Their intersection has only the 0 vector. But how do I relate the intersection to this question?

Comment: Thanks, I have got it now!

Comment: Great! Go ahead and post your own answer, then you can accept it.